# Reindex a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe in Python.

```
          datetime           machineID
0   2021-10-01 00:00:00        1.0
1   2021-10-01 00:00:00        2.0
2   2021-10-01 00:00:00        3.0
3   2021-10-01 00:00:00        4.0
4   2021-10-01 00:00:00        5.0
... ... ...
443 2021-10-07 12:00:00       28.0
444 2021-10-07 12:00:00       29.0
445 2021-10-07 12:00:00       30.0
446 2021-10-07 12:00:00       31.0
447 2021-10-07 12:00:00       32.0
```

There are 7 days in this dataframe from 2021-10-01 to 2021-10-07. This is indexed as per datetime like for every machineID, all the machineIDs come for that date then for next date all machineIDs come and so on.

What I want is, I want to reindex this dataframe such that for each machineID, all 7 dates come then for next machineID all dates come. Something like this,

```
          datetime           machineID
0   2021-10-01 00:00:00        1.0
1   2021-10-02 00:00:00        1.0
2   2021-10-03 00:00:00        1.0
3   2021-10-04 00:00:00        1.0
4   2021-10-05 00:00:00        1.0
... ... ...
443 2021-10-03 12:00:00       32.0
444 2021-10-04 12:00:00       32.0
445 2021-10-05 12:00:00       32.0
446 2021-10-06 12:00:00       32.0
447 2021-10-07 12:00:00       32.0
```

I am not able to find any method to do so.

Comment: How looks second group?

Comment: Need `df.sort_values(by=['machineID', 'datetime'], ignore_index=True)`

Comment: If you want to sort the values first but also reset the index (if the new df is the format you want), you could sort by  `df.sort_values(['machineID', 'datetime'], inplace=True)` and then overwrite the df to reset index in accordance with the sorting result  `df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think you may be looking for df.sort_values()**

```
df.sort_values(by=['machineID', 'datetime'])
```

You may need to tinker with the parameter <ascending=True/False> to get your desired result.

Documentation available here:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please upvote the question as well :)

Answer (score 0):

you should tell pandas to reindex on your custom sort column

```
df =  df.sort_values(by='datetime',ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply sort your dataframe by machineID, something like :

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['machineID'], ignore_index=True)
```